# Multiple data validation to excell

Tags: excel

I have the following formula that  accept only values like LL-XXXXXX where x is a number, and its working fine {=AND(LEFT(A59;3)="LL-";LEN(A59)=8)}. Now i would like to add no to to allow duplicated values option to the column.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should return true if there is a duplicate in the range.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A59,A59)>1
```

You could enclose this with a NOT() function to include it within the AND() function.

```
{=AND(LEFT(A59,3)="LL-",LEN(A59)=8,Not(COUNTIF(A1:A59,A59)>1))}
```